# How to format date in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to format date `YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00.000` to `YYYY-MM`.

Here is a example.

```
2005-09-06 00:00:00.000
```

should become

```
2005-09
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `CONVERT/CAST/DATEPART/LEFT/RIGHT` are your friends

Comment: Please give me a example.

Comment: @Allen_Delon Please read the documentation. lad2025 even gave you the functions to look for.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), '2005-09-06 00:00:00.000', 120) AS [YYYY-MM]
```

and here you are a list of SQL Server date Formats :

http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Answer (score 1):

to get `YYYY-MM` you can use **any** parameter like shown below..

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), '2005-09-06 00:00:00.000', 120) 
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), '2005-09-06 00:00:00.000', 121)
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), '2005-09-06 00:00:00.000', 126)
```

**Note**: Keep in mind that these parameters originally returns a long string, and we are capturing string till *YYYY-MM*. Below are real return formats of these parameters..

```
120 - yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss(24h)
121 - yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.mmm
126 - yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.mmm
```

see first seven return characters in these formats are same, hence, you can use any of them.